# Removing Cypress default proxy settings

Tags: proxy, cypress

I'm having trouble to load the page of my application under test when running Cypress test. After long investigation I figured out that Cypress is using a corporate proxy which is retrieved from my environment variables according to documentation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#View-proxy-settings-in-Cypress
This proxy is no longer active so I remove it from my environment variables but Cypress is still using it even after restarting both cypress and VsCode.
I also tried the following solutions:
clean up Cypress cache folder
uninstall Cypress and install it again

Installing Cypress on a teammate's machine who never had the proxy environment variables configured worked fine.
My question is: Why Cypress is still retrieving the HTTP_PROXY env var which no longer exists ? How to remove this from Cypress settings ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you look into this: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS

Comment: Hi @AlapanDas, I already went through this documentation and I did not find any hint to help me getting rid of the proxy settings in Cypress

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and it was driving me nuts. I eventually remembered that I had set a proxy value for [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-config?v=true), which you can confirm by running `npm get` and then delete the specific proxy value by running `npm config delete [value]`. I know this question is a few years old at this point and OP probably got around this issue already, but I hope this can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

environment variables are available in cypress through :

**1) Approach 1**

adding environment variable through terminal or command line as : CYPRESS_

eg : CYPRESS_TEST create variable TEST

you can see all the variables by typing set in cmd and env in shell , search for cypress in that

**2)Approach 2:**

to environment file or config file:

check if these files has proxy environment variables:

[image]

**3) using plugin file **

check the index.js in plugin folder for

```
config.env
```

see if you have proxy variable set in any of these location ( Or from tests ) and try to remove it

Comment: Hello @PDHide, thanks for your answer. I tried to display the list of env variables in shell but there is no http_proxy settings there. Then I created a cypress.env.json file with http_proxy and https_proxy set to null to overwrite the default value but still no luck. I checked out index.js but nothing there either. I still cannot figure out where Cypress is getting this setting from.

Comment: @Mghar see if it helps and accept by clicking the tick sign

Comment: @Mghar you have to check for varaibles starting with the string cypress

Comment: ,I didn't find any environment variable starting with CYPRESS

Comment: @Mghar which os are you using could you see system proxy is enabled  ?

Comment: if you are using windows goes to pc>propert>environtment variables and see if ther is system or user variable http_proxy or https_proxy

Comment: That was the first check I did. I have removed http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy variables and restarted  vscode and cypress but it still appears in cypress settings

Comment: How are you opening cypress ? Did you close and opened cypress ? Cypress take environment variable from the terminal or cmd session from which it was opened so you have to close cypress and the  cmd on which it was opened in and then start it again